Naming and grouping nested random effect variables
I had a question about how to name and group nested random effects for a mixed effects model.
I ran a lab experiment where there are 3 treatments, A, B, C.  Each treatment has a main tank that feeds water into to two treatment tanks- a left and a right tank. There are 10 organisms of two species mixed in each treatment tank. When I'm designating the "tank" random effect variable in R, should their tankID be coded as left vs. right, or should all tanks be given a unique identifier, ex.:
A_left A_right B_left B_right C_left C_right?
I think it should be the second one because it's really not the left/right designation that matters- I don't really expect all the "left" tanks to be similar to each other- it is the effect of 10 organisms being grouped together in an individual tank, experiencing a similar environment, and interacting with each other in unique ways that matters. But I just wanted to confirm because I've seen it run the other way.
Also, if I code it so all tanks have a unique ID, do I have to specify that tank is nested under treatment in the model? Ex. lme(response ~ treatment * species, random = ~1 | treatment / tankID, data = data)? Or is it ok to run it without the nesting, lme(response ~ treatment * species, random = ~1 | tankID, data = data)?
Thanks!

Unique identifiers (A_left, A_right, etc.) are probably safer. For the discussion below I'm going to use utank for tanks specified uniquely (A_left etc.) and tank for tanks specified non-uniquely (left/right).
Random effects are specified slightly different for lme (nlme package) and lmer (lme4 package).
Since you've included a main effect of treatment in your fixed effect model (as part of treatment*species == 1 + treatment + species + treatment:species), you should not use the nested syntax — that is appropriate only when you want to include variability among treatments and variability among tanks within treatments as random-effect terms.  You should use random = ~ 1 | utank or (I think this works) random = ~ 1 | tank:treatment) so that you're only including variability among tanks within treatments (because the among-treatment differences are already included in the fixed effects).
To make sure you got it right, you should check the summary for the number of random-effects variances reported (there should be one, not two) and the number of levels of the grouping variable (6 in your example).
